# Angular Keycloak The 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header contains multiple values '*

Tags: angularjs, keycloak

I have deployed my front-end angular app with keycloak enabled. Also have a java rest based back-end for communication. When i run the app keycloak shows the login page, Then after i login it does not shows anything.

XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://test.ssdiary.com:2222/auth/realms/app1/protocol/openid-connect/token. Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: The 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header contains multiple values '*, http://test.ssdiary.com', but only one is allowed. Origin 'http://test.ssdiary.com' is therefore not allowed access.

GET http://test.ssdiary.com:2222/auth/realms/app1/protocol/openid-connect/login…ame.html/init?client_id=srms-frontend&origin=http%3A%2F%2Ftest.ssdiary.com 403 (Forbidden)**strong text**

**Header from network tab**

```
Access-Control-Allow-Credentials:true
Access-Control-Allow-Headers:accept, authorization, content-type, x-requested-with
Access-Control-Allow-Methods:GET, POST, OPTIONS, PUT
Access-Control-Allow-Origin:*
Access-Control-Max-Age:1
Connection:keep-alive
Content-Length:0
Date:Fri, 09 Jun 2017 04:57:38 GMT
Server:WildFly/10
X-Powered-By:Undertow/1
```

Comment: Can you show us your request headers?

Comment: From console network tab. right?

Comment: @31piy check the updated question

Answer (score 0):

Please read the specifications of the `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` header [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Access-Control-Allow-Origin).

> For requests without credentials, the server may specify "*" as a wildcard, thereby allowing any origin to access the resource.

You are setting `Access-Control-Allow-Credentials:true` in your request. Thus, multiple origins are not allowed to access the returned content. Try to send a single origin as the value of `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` from your server.

Comment: does changing `Access-Control-Allow-Credentials:true` to `Access-Control-Allow-Credentials:false` will solve my problem??

Comment: Yes! It should. Or try to remove that header from request altogether.

Comment: no, same error. I have added the `Access-Control-Allow-Credentials:false` on keycloak.json file.

Comment: @boycod3 - You cannot simply set that to `false`, the API should also needs to turn it off. Why don't you remove the `*` from the API response headers instead?